# Why public ref in c++ class definition

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, managed-c++

First of all I want to make clear that 'm all new to C++, so this might be a simple and somewhat obvious question. In the C++ book I'm reading called C++ Primer, a class is defined by writing:

```
class classname{
public:

private:

};
```

However, in VS2008 the compiler didnt like this. But by adding public ref before class, as in:

```
public ref class classname{
```

it went through in the compiler. Can anyone please explain what the difference is between defining only with class and with public ref class? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: This is the question you wanted to ask: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195572/compiling-standard-c-in-visual-studio-non-net

Comment: "didn't like this" is a not a error message that VS2008 produces. If the OP had specified the error message, perhaps the answers wouldn't have been so awful.

Answer (score 23):

The `ref` syntax is a Microsoft extension used only in Managed C++. By the sounds of things you have flicked the `/clr` compiler switch on by mistake when creating your project. If all you want to do is to create real C++ programs, then you will want to revert that.

Comment: Choosing the wrong type of project in Visual Studio may automatically switch the /clr on without you realizing.  I wanted to create a new dll library and ended up making this mistake.  Instead I should have used the Win32 Console Application project type which was not obvious to me as a newbie.  See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Clarification... Microsoft produced TWO ways to interact with C++ from .Net

The first (which violated ISO C++) was "Managed C++" This is long obsolete.
The second (ISO compliant, active even today) is C++/CLI

This matters because when the wrong name is used, then search results lead the reader down primrose paths...

Answer (score 7):

You're reading a book call C++ Primer which teaches the [C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B) programming language, whereas you're attempting to create a program telling VC++ the code is in [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), a different programming language....

Comment: +1 Programming in the same language that you learnt usually helps.

Answer (score 4):

You (*edit:* and other users) tagged this question with:

- Two **programming languages**: **[C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B)** and **[C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI)**,
- One commercial **Integrated Development Environment (IDE)** by Microsoft: **[Visual C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B)**, which lets you program in three different languages ([C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)), C++ and C++/CLI). In the post you mention **[Microsoft Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio)**, which is a superset of Visual C++.
- One **set of language extensions**: [**Managed C++**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_C%2B%2B), which has historically refered to quite a few different things and, frankly, I'm not sure what it means now :)

However, your first goal should be to **learn how to configure Visual C++ to program in the language of your choice, C++**.

As usual, a good way to find an answer to this question is to type it in the "Ask Question" page and see which related questions are suggested. This is the best one, I think: [**compiling "standard" C++ in visual studio (non .net)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1195572/compiling-standard-c-in-visual-studio-non-net).

Comment: * AProgrammer retagged the question adding C++/CLI after reading the question. The OP didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you learning the standard C/C++ language? if the answer is yes then that syntax is concerning the Microsoft  C++/CLI language...

look at : [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx)

Try to use Eclipse with C++ extension instead. It cames with all you need to create and execute a STANDARD C++ program!

[Eclipse download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)

Comment: He's reading a C++ book, so I would presume he's learning C++.

Why the advert for Eclipse? VC++ is a perfecting good IDE / compiler to create a C++ program on Windows. You just need to make sure you select the right project types. A problem that still exist with something like Eclipse if someone decide to select say a Java project and then trys to write a C++ program.

Comment: @KTC: Because VC++ actively diverts you from ISO C++ path. "Secure" CRT, anyone?